# How to use MOSFET for load switch applications

Tags: mosfet, switches

[image]

I would like to do something like this application note:
http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9093-D.PDF

And I'm using this transistor:
https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FD/FDS5670.pdf

For me Vin = 20 V, and I apply 5 V on the gate.
Load = 22k

But it's like the MOS is always open. That's I don't understand, Vgs > Vth, so why is it always open?
And what I should do for make it work?

Thanks
edit: Add schematic, sorry I forgot it

Comment: Where is the schematic of your circuit?

Comment: I edited it. Sorry I forgot it

Comment: That needs to be a low side switch not a source follower.

Comment: You're using an NMOS, in the "high side" configuration as in your schematic, the NMOS will only will act as a low value resistor when it is in triode mode. For that the gate voltage needs to be higher than the drain voltage. Make V1 25 V and the NMOS fully conduct. R2 of 1 milli ohm is rather pointless, you should remove it or give it a proper value.

Comment: I'm new in the design, what is the difference between low side switch and source follower? They look like similar. I don't think I use in high side, because mu load is on the source. Am I wrong? The 1 mOhms is a "sensor" resistor. I wanted a switch, something with the smallest Vds.

Comment: Low side switch and source follower are unrelated circuits, google for both and see the difference yourself. A source follower isn't suitable as a switch, it is a voltage buffer. If you use an NMOS with the load on the source that **is** called high side switching. High side means that the switch (here: the NMOS) is in the line to + node of the supply. Low side switching means switching to ground. Instead of 1 mOhm resistor for sensing it is more clear to use a 0 (zero) ohm resistor or a zero volt voltage source.

Answer (score 5):

In order to adequately turn the MOSFET on there needs to be "several" volts between gate and source. If you apply 5 volts to the gate and the gate-source threshold voltage is exceeded you will begin to see some voltage at the source but you won't see 20 volts because this is a source follower circuit.

A better circuit is to put your 22 kohm resistor in series with the drain up to 20 volts and have the source connected to ground/0 volts. This is called a common-source configuration and you will be able to switch virtually the full rail across the load.

Alternatively, if you need a ground connected load you would use a PMOS FET: -

[image]

R3 stops the full 20 volts being applied across GS of the PMOS FET because that might otherwise be close to the limit for a typical device.

Comment: Thank you for your verry good answer. If get it, every time I want to use a MOSFET as control (vd = vs if vg is ON), I should give a Vg close from Vd. Looking at Id(Vgs), I understand that. So I couldn't control a MOSFET with 3.3 V (if Vd is higher than 3.3V)? What is the need of Q1?

Comment: Q1 is to allow a low voltage from typically an MCU to switch Q1 and that does the proper level shifting to control the MOSFET. BTW I've added an extra resistor...

Comment: Ah, yes, Q1 has the 20 V on collector, it can do 0V to 20 V. Thanks